# Integration of Differential Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In the paper of Dalgaard and Strulik (2014) titled "Optimal Aging and Death" they use following differential equation: 
\begin{equation}
    \dot{D}(t)  = \mu (D(t) - E)
\end{equation}
They ingerate the above equation and get the result like this: 
\begin{equation}
    D(t) = D_{0} e^{\mu t} - E e^{\mu t} + E 
\end{equation}
I want to know the steps of how they came to this solution?

Comment: Is $\mu$ a constant or a function? 

Taking the derivative of both sides of the second equation gets 

$D'(t)=\mu e^{\mu t}(D_0-E)$ 

but I am not sure how helpful this is to you, since there is a factor of $e^{\mu t}$ that isn't present in the first equation.

Comment: μ is a constant. and Can you derive the second equation from the first? I need to derive second equation from the first by integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.eeassoc.org/doc/paper/20130918_164544_DALGAARD-STRULIK.PDF&ved=0ahUKEwi8u7DpkfnRAhXIDcAKHYMoDCoQFggnMAI&usg=AFQjCNGjToj9BkshBLY9GoQyTU6Qpb-nHg) you referred to and saw that you forgot to provide one piece of information:
$$D(0)=D_0$$
Your ODE is first order and autonomous.

Therefore, you can separate the variables as follows:
$$\frac{dD}{dt}=\mu(D-E)$$
$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{D-E}~dD=\int \mu~dt$$
Integrating both sides gives:
$$\ln(D-E)=\mu t+C$$
Exponentiate both sides:
$$D-E=e^{\mu t+C}$$
$$D-E=e^{\mu t}\cdot e^C$$
Let $e^C=k$:
$$D-E=ke^{\mu t}$$
Therefore, we have the following general solution:
$$D(t)=ke^{\mu t}+E \tag{1}$$
Now, consider your initial condition $D(0)=D_0$.
Substitute this into equation $(1)$ to find $k$, and then substitute the value of $k$ you obtained into $(1)$.

If done correctly, you should get the solution you've provided.

If you don't get to the solution, please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

They don't integrate the equation, they solve it. It goes like this:

Write $\dot{D}(t)$ as $\frac{dD}{dt}$. Then you separate the variables:

$$dD = \mu (D- E) dt $$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dD}{\mu (D- E)} = dt $$

And now you integrate:

$$\int_{D_0}^D \frac{dD'}{ (D'- E)} = \mu t$$
$$\Rightarrow  \log{\left(\frac{D-E}{D_0 -E}\right)} =\mu t $$

and solve for $D$:

$$\log{(D-E)} = \mu t + \log{(D_0 -E)} $$
$$\Rightarrow D-E = e^{\mu t}(D_0 -E) $$
$$\Rightarrow D = e^{\mu t}(D_0 -E) +E $$

Comment: In the context of differential equations, *integration* is synonym of resolution; and a solution is also called an *integral*.

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard anyone say that. But it seems to my like a not *so* good choice of words...

Comment: What you use to call integration and integral just correspond to the particular case of the differential equation $y'=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

\begin{align}
\frac{dD}{dt} &= \mu D - \mu E \\
\frac{1}{D-E}dD &= \mu dt \\
\log\left(\frac{D(t)-E}{D_0-E}\right) &= \mu t \\
\frac{D(t)-E}{D_0-E} &= e^{\mu t}\\
D(t) &= D_0 e^{\mu t} - E e^{\mu t} + E
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

With $G(t):=D(t)-E$, the equation simplifies to

$$\dot G(t)=\mu G(t)$$ which is a very classical one (first order linear with constant coefficients, both homogenous and separable). The solution is known to be

$$G(t)=G_0e^{\mu t}$$ where $G_0:=G(0)$. (You easily find this result by integrating $dG/G=\mu\,dt$.)

Then

$$D(t)=(D_0-E)e^{\mu t}+E.$$